# find the database of a given collection

Tags: mongodb

is there any command to find the databases which contains given collection in mongoDB

```
MongoDB Enterprise TestCluster-shard-0:PRIMARY> show dbs
admin               0.000GB
sample_airbnb       0.051GB
sample_analytics    0.009GB
sample_geospatial   0.001GB
sample_mflix        0.041GB
sample_supplies     0.001GB
sample_training     0.059GB
sample_weatherdata  0.002GB
```

Comment: `db.admin.find().pretty()`

Comment: i'm getting error `"errmsg" : "cannot do raw queries on admin in atlas"` when executing on admin db

Answer (score 2):

**(1) Using mtools:**

[mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools) is a collection of helper scripts to parse, filter, and visualize MongoDB log files.

`mlogfilter` is a `mtools` script to reduce the amount of information from MongoDB log files. You can specify a pattern or a word and search the log file. The collection name is usually specified as a "namespace" which is a combination of database and collection `("<database>.<collection>")`.

For example, look for the collection name:

```
mlogfilter mongod.log --word myCollection
```

This might return a lot of lines; you can just look at few lines and find your collection. There are a lot of options by which you can restrict the output (see the [mtools documentation](http://blog.rueckstiess.com/mtools/)).

**(2) From mongo Shell:**

You can list all the databases ([listDatabases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/index.html)) and all the collections ([listCollections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listCollections/)) from `mongo` shell. You can write a script to search each database for the specific collection.

Comment: Thanks for your response. when i do db.getCollectionNames(), gives the collection in the present db. But i want to search in all the dbs for a connected cluster. is there any admin commands which i can execute to find from the shell

Comment: Yes. `db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1, nameOnly: true} )`

Comment: HI Prasad, it gives me all the database name. i want to list the database only those which contain the collection which i gave

Comment: You have to iterate the database list and check each database if the specific collection exists.